# Problem when implementing gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("D:\data\diabetes.csv")
y = df[["Outcome"]]
x = df.iloc[:, [1]]

# Applying linear regression
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = reg.predict(x_test)
r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

# Applying gradient descent
class GDRegressor:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, epochs=100):

        self.coef_ = None
        self.intercept_ = None
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs


    def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
        # init your coefficients from X_train because coefficients are equal to the number of features
        self.intercept_ = 0
        self.coef_ = np.ones(x_train.shape[1])  # [1] take the columns from (353, 10) <-- shape of X_train

        for i in range(self.epochs):

            # update all the coefficients and the intercept
            y_hat = np.dot(x_train, self.coef_) + self.intercept_

            # print("Shape of y_hat",y_hat.shape)
            intercept_der = -2 * np.mean(y_train - y_hat)
            self.intercept_ = self.intercept_ - (self.lr * intercept_der)

            coef_der = -2 * np.dot((y_train - y_hat), x_train) / x_train.shape[0]
            self.coef_ = self.coef_ - (self.lr * coef_der)

        print(self.intercept_, self.coef_)


    def predict(self, x_test):
        return np.dot(x_test, self.coef_) + self.intercept_

gdr = GDRegressor(epochs=100, learning_rate=0.5)
gdr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-135-33c959c29314> in <module>
            ----> 1 gdr.fit(x_train,y_train)
        
            <ipython-input-130-42d541ead6b9> in fit(self, x_train, y_train)
                 17             y_hat = np.dot(x_train,self.coef_) + self.intercept_
                 18             #print("Shape of y_hat",y_hat.shape)
            ---> 19             intercept_der = -2 * np.mean(y_train - y_hat)
                 20             self.intercept_ = self.intercept_ - (self.lr * intercept_der)
                 21 
        
            ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
                693     def f(self, other, axis=default_axis, level=None, fill_value=None):
                694 
            --> 695         other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis)
                696 
                697         if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):
        
            ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in _align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis)
                642 
                643         if right.ndim == 1:
            --> 644             right = to_series(right)
                645 
                646         elif right.ndim == 2:
        
            ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in to_series(right)
                634             if len(left.columns) != len(right):
                635                 raise ValueError(
            --> 636                     msg.format(req_len=len(left.columns), given_len=len(right))
                637                 )
                638             right = left._constructor_sliced(right, index=left.columns)
        
            ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 537
```

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.  Good luck 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the dot product in this line:

```py
coef_der = -2 * np.dot((y_train - y_hat), x_train) / x_train.shape[0]
```

which needs to be replaced with:

```py
coef_der = - 2 * np.dot(x_train.T, (y_train - y_hat)) / x_train.shape[0]
```

Once this is fixed the results from your `GDRegressor` will be in line with the ones from scikit-learn `LinearRegression`, see the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Data
x, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=4, n_informative=3, bias=2, noise=10, random_state=2)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

# Preprocessing
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

# Gradient Descent
class GDRegressor:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, epochs=100):

        self.coef_ = None
        self.intercept_ = None
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs

    def fit(self, x_train, y_train):

        self.intercept_ = 0
        self.coef_ = np.ones(x_train.shape[1])

        for i in range(self.epochs):

            y_hat = np.dot(x_train, self.coef_) + self.intercept_

            intercept_der = - 2 * np.mean(y_train - y_hat)
            self.intercept_ = self.intercept_ - (self.lr * intercept_der)

            coef_der = - 2 * np.dot(x_train.T, (y_train - y_hat)) / x_train.shape[0]
            self.coef_ = self.coef_ - (self.lr * coef_der)

    def predict(self, x_test):

        return np.dot(x_test, self.coef_) + self.intercept_

gdr = GDRegressor(epochs=100, learning_rate=0.5)
gdr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred_gdr = gdr.predict(x_test)

print(gdr.intercept_)
# 3.770775418017894

print(gdr.coef_)
# [-0.24833521 35.02590365 35.39315588 77.81917572]

print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred_gdr))
# 0.9889061967355228

# Linear regression
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred_reg = reg.predict(x_test)

print(reg.intercept_)
# 3.7707754180178954

print(reg.coef_)
# [-0.24833521 35.02590365 35.39315588 77.81917572]

print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred_reg))
# 0.9889061967355228
```